# Geographic/ethnic distribution of Neanderthal DNA in modern humans

Tags: anthropology

There is a really good chance that various human populations have different levels of Neanderthal DNA in their genes.

And yet, the only thing I was able to find is the percentage of Neanderthal DNA in Europe, Asia and Africa.

Are there any studies with a finer resolution, such as regions, countries etc.?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Are you looking for a more fine grained (country-level say) frequency of Neanderthal DNA? Can you please to link to what you found so far? If you can't find country-level frequency of Neanderthal, it is probably because there is too little population structure at this small scale to be able to see any difference. Note, however, that I expect northern Africa to be much more Neanderthal than in Central Africa.

Comment: http://www.genetics.org/content/early/2013/02/04/genetics.112.148213
Region-level (Northern/Southern Europe, Middle East, India) data will be sufficient. Country-level data might produce some interesting insights.

Comment: [Here](http://www.genetics.org/content/194/1/199.full) is a link to the full text of the final published article.